# Static Members Issue - JasperReports for .Net over jni4Net

Tags: java, .net, interop, jasper-reports, java-native-interface

I'm trying to fill a report with empty datasource like this

```
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(@"D:\ImagesReport.jasper", null);
```

Usually the program crashes without notice, but I used watch window and found that this is what I get

```
   at net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethodPtr(Class clazz, MethodId methodIdNative, Value[] args)
   at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(String par0, Map par1)
   in D:\jasper4net\Jasper4net\net\sf\jasperreports\engine\JasperFillManager.generated.cs:line 149
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably not implemented yet, please create [issue](https://github.com/jni4net/jni4net/issues) for it.